# Is it ok to run dryer duct under an electrical panel?

Tags: dryer, ducts

My current dryer vent is preventing me from enclosing my back porch.
I have a basement window I can use to vent the dryer, but it's on the other side of my electrical panel. Is it ok to run the flexible duct underneath?

Context [image]
The previous owners of my house used [unconventional material](https://mobileimages.lowes.com/productimages/84c95f4a-e12d-422b-b758-294b3f585c89/48779450.jpg) for the siding so I can't create a new opening myself.

Comment: The vent will probably be okay.  It is all the other stuff under  and in front/beside the panel that will be the problem.  Panels are suppose to have free open/clear space in front of them

Comment: You're right. The shelving and cart would have to move away from the panel anyway.

Comment: Distance and 90 degree elbows in the vent will be a problem.  I think maybe at least four elbows needed.  Read dryer instructions carefully for venting.

Comment: On the outside you want it pointing down, otherwise rain etc will come in

Comment: You are a 'brave' person running a gas line over the edge of an electrical panel.

Comment: Could you route the hose under the ceiling and still have room to move though?   Or relocate the dryer so it is straight under the window?

Comment: No reason you can't create a new opening yourself; it's simply more difficult with that material than it would be with something more conventional.  Chisel and cut out an opening larger than you need, then frame, flash, fill as needed, and cover with trim.

Answer (score 7):

No.

> **NEC 110.26(E) Dedicated Equipment Space.** All switchboards, switchgear, panelboards, and motor control centers shall be located in
> dedicated spaces and protected from damage. Exception: Control
> equipment that by its very nature or because of other rules of the
> Code must be adjacent to or within sight of its operating machinery
> shall be permitted in those locations.
>
> (1) Indoor. Indoor installations shall comply with 110.26(E) (1)(a)
> through (E)(1)(d).
>
> **(a) Dedicated Electrical Space. The space equal to the width and depth of the equipment and extending from the floor to a height of 1.8
> m (6 ft) above the equipment or to the structural ceiling, whichever
> is lower, shall be dedicated to the electrical installation. No
> piping, ducts, leak protection apparatus, or other equipment foreign
> to the electrical installation shall be located in this zone.**

Comment: So that yellow gas line is also against the regulations.

Comment: Yes, the gas line violates The NEC.

Comment: Looks like the gas line could be pushed over into the corner (but might take some rejiggering) though.

Comment: Since the existing route of the vent looks comparatively sane- at least by comparison with the gas and plumbing pipes- it might be better to consider whether it could be rerouted outside.